# Using Hadamard's Formula to show that the radius of convergence of $\sum z^{n!}$ is $1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Background:** Recall that Hadarmard's formula for the radius of convergence of a complex power series $\sum a_n z^n$ is as follows:

$$
R = \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{limsup} \left| a_n \right|^{1/n}}
$$

**Goal:** Show that the series

$$
\sum z^{n!}
$$

has radius of convergence equal to $1$ via Hadamard's formula.

**Attempt:**

1. In order to obtain the limsup in the denominator above, we have to convert the power series $\sum z^{n!}$ into form $\sum a_n z^n$ so that we can check that the expression

   $$
   \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{limsup} \left|a_n \right|^{1/n}
   $$

   is equal to $1$ as desired.
2. Now consider that

   $$
   z^{n!} = \left(z^{(n!-n)}\right) z^n 
   $$
3. Then if $|z| < 1$, we have that

   $$
   \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{limsup} \left|z^{(n!-n)} \right|^{1/n} = 1
   $$
4. If $|z| = 1$, we have that

   $$
   \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{limsup} \left|z^{(n!-n)} \right|^{1/n} = 1
   $$
5. If $|z| > 1$, we have that

   $$
   \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{limsup} \left|z^{(n!-n)} \right|^{1/n} = \infty
   $$

Given the massive dependence of the $a_n$ on $z$, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: There's no need. If $|z|<1$, it's dominated by a convergent series. If $|z|\ge 1$, the terms don't converge to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write this as a series, write this as a series! That is, as $\sum\limits_na_nz^n$ *where the sequence $(a_n)$ is independent of $z$.*

Here $a_n=1$ when $n$ is in $K=\{k!\,;\,k\geqslant0\}$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise, hence $|a_n|^{1/n}$ is always $0$ or $1$ and is $1$ infinitely often (since $K$ is infinite). In particular, $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=1.$$

Comment: And there are much simpler and shorter approaches than Hadamard's formula (a vastly overrated tool, based on the questions on this site).

Comment: I edited something in your answer, I hope you don't mind. It was a broken code.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** All coefficients have $a_n\in\{0,1\}$. No matter how big $n$ is there is a later term with $a_n=1$. Therefore,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=1
$$

Answer (score 2):

No, the coefficients of your series are $$a_m=\begin{cases}1&\text { if }m=n!\\0&\text{ else }\end{cases}$$

Can you try again with this?